# How to connect to Firestore with dart (without flutter)

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm writing a backend in `dart`. How can I connect to a `Firestore` without using `flutter`. I used the [cloud_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore) package in my app but all resources I checked are based on `flutter` no standalone usage.

Comment: Seems this has been already answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71388053/how-to-access-firestore-in-dart-on-server-side